# GLFW not working in Python anymore (Error 65543)

Tags: python, glfw

I am using Python bindings for GLFW for a project of mine.
I'm having a really strange GLFW error in that my code was working 5 minutes ago, and then suddenly it doesn't run anymore even though I have changed absolutely nothing with the GLFW part of my code or even anything that has something to do with it.

I can run this fine:

```
glfw.init()
glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)
```

But as soon as I try to run
`glfw.create_window(800, 600, "__DELETEME__", None, None)`, it crashes and returns this error:

```
glfw.GLFWError: (65543) b'GLX: Failed to create context: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)'
```

Now that isn't particularily helpful, and I've checked both with the GLFW docs and the PyGLFW "docs" and `BadValue` is mentioned nowhere.

I'd like to know why this is happening, and as I said 5 minutes ago this was working and now I can't even create a window.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I've tested the same code on another computer and it works fine. Did the GLFW library somehow get corrupted?

Comment: Roughly the same issue here. Did you solve/fix it? I now have 2 ridiculous 'GLFW emitter error' messages.

Comment: Hey everyone, I found a hacky fix. Initialize the window somewhere else, like in my case directly inside an IPython 7.22.0 console. Then, for me, the window context was restored.

Comment: Somebody had the same issue one year later, so mind if I ask if this is still an issue? What version of GLFW is used?